# How to make third-party request in backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I need to use backbone in this part without use the server, just in client side.
Need: When user click on button then has to make a request in third-party(different domain). I have to grab the answer and show to user. The problem is how i pass my grab data to view
OBS: I don`t have this model in rails, it's just fake (pretend)
I already tried:

```
class App.Routers.Datas extends Backbone.Router
 routes:
 '': 'show'
 initialize: ->
   @collection = new App.Collections.Data()
   @collection.fetch({reset: true})

 show: ->
   view = new App.Views.DatasShow(collection: @collection)
   $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

Where im trying fetch data

```
class App.Collections.Datas extends Backbone.Collection

 model: App.Models.Data

 fetch: -> # override method
 $.ajax '/url', #third-party request
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: (res, status, xhr) -> # the problem is here, how to pass data to a collection?
    @collection = res.data
    return @collection
  error: (xhr, status, err) ->
```

View

```
class App.Views.DatasShow extends Backbone.View

template: JST['datas/show']
render: ->
  $(@el).html(@template(fetched: @collection))
  this
```

show.jst.eco

```
<%= @fetched.length %>
```

Comment: is this "third-party" url under a different domain? then you may need  to set {dataType: 'jsonp'} for all of your ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't to override the **fetch** method; you just need to define your **url** and you also need to override the **parse** method which is automatically called after fetching to parse the returned response and assign it to the collection http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

```
class App.Collections.Datas extends Backbone.Collection

  model: App.Models.Data

  initialize: ->
    @url = 'Enter URL here' # The fetch method will use this url by default

  parse:(response, options)->
    super(response.data, options)
```

**PS**

the word **data** is the plural of **datum**